# intent.send - show my app to share only on one defined app

Tags: java, android, android-intent, share

I want my app to receive Links from one other app - and only from this app.
The other app provides Links to share and i want to show my appicon only in the list of "send to" apps there.
Is it possible? How do i have to define the intent in manifest?

```
<intent-filter
    android:label="my app">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible?

No, unless you are the author of that other app. If you are, then you can craft some sort of `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` structure that nobody else is likely to use (e.g., some unique MIME type).

Comment: Ok, even it's not the answer i hoped to find - thanks a lot!